# Three Variables Extrapolation in R

Tags: r

How does one go about doing **extrapolation** for **3 Variables** in R using this example? I have read up on this and found a path to attempt to do this. I know approx does not work for this since it does **interpolation**

```
Height  Direction   Velocity
91      152.7       7.5
737     179.8       9.1
1434    238.1      11.2
2999    275.3      16.6
4204    278.7      18.3
5580    279        24.3
7190    280.5      33.2
9151    284.1      38.8
10354   285.6      39
11814   285.9      38.4
13674   285.6      30
16252   281.9      19.9
18439   291.4      16.3
20488   327.7      15.3
23680   25.9       19.6
26234   30.7       23.1
30699   24.3       31.9
```

And say I want to get the other variables for 
assumed heights of

```
Height  Direction   Velocity
31300      ?           ? 
33750      ?           ?
35650      ?           ?
37950      ?           ?
38840      ?           ?
```

I followed an example found on here and I got this (shown below). How does one do this in R?

```
> df[,Direction := ifelse(is.na(Direction), 
+                                        predict(lm(Direction, data=.SD), .SD),
+                               Direction)
+          , by=Height
+          ][, Velocity := ifelse(is.na(Velocity),
+                                     predict(lm(Velocity, data=.SD), .SD),
+                                 Velocity) 
+            , by=Height
+            ]
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , `:=`(Direction, ifelse(is.na(Direction),  : 
  unused argument (by = Height)
```

Comment: That code requires that you load `library(data.table)`, and that your data is in data table form

Comment: Your attempt assumes a linear model (via `lm(...)`). Your data is not remotely linear.

Comment: @jlhoward Thanks for pointing that out. I am not really familiar with R and the various statistical models which I am certain should be utilized. Which model would you suggest? Continuous?

Comment: You need to find some statistical model that can predict direction and velocity given only height -  that's a statistics question not an R question; R has a library for virtually any type of model you can find. Are these the only observations you have?

Comment: @NoxNoctis I have observations for 30 years but they are all at 17 levels each as the data shows. I apologize for asking a statistical question. Thanks.

Comment: @Gunnerfan, no problem - but fair warning, you may get better answers at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). Do you have reason to believe that the relationship in each year changes?

Comment: @NoxNoctis Yes I have a reason to believe that they do, this is why I am using the mean of each variables for days or even months. I am simulating a volcanic eruption which I need to extrapolate to higher values but can not for the life of me figure out how to do since the data is not fitting any trendline (power, linear, etc). The only fit is the moving average which I'm sure is incorrect. I have figured out how to calculate the velocity at assumed heights but the wind direction is mind baffling. Sorry for the long response.

Comment: @Gunnerfan Is there any way you could provide a link to a csv? Copying from the question manually is very time consuming to play around with this data... I don't know what pattern your data looks like but my guess is that a polynomial line could be fit to it

Comment: @NoxNoctis This is the link http://www.filedropper.com/meandata